# Unable to use git to push all files using wildcard with Ansible

Tags: git, ansible, runtime-error, runtime

I'm planning to push all the files and folders under "/app/gitfiles" on my local system to an on-premise remote git server.

Below is the command I execute:

```
1. export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/private/id_rsa -F /dev/null"

2.
git init /app/gitfiles

3. 
ls -qa /app/gitfiles/
.  ..  CRM.ear  .git

#Verified that the .git folder got created

4.
git add -a /app/gitfiles/*
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

5.
git commit -m "Adding new files to repo"

6.
git push
```

As you can see I was expecting /app/gitfiles/ to be added to git stage @ step 4. In this sample case CRM.ear folder 
But unfortunately, it fails with the error shown in point 4.

Can you please suggest what is the issue with my command @step 4?

The end-goal is to write an ansible playbook [probably ansible git module] to do the above task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a 3.5 step like `cd /app/gitfiles/` before you can start doing stuff like adding/committing.

Comment: I'd recommend to rewrite 4: `git add -a /app/gitfiles/*` into `git -C /app/gitfiles/ add -a .`

Answer (score 0):

In addition of a preliminary cd in the right folder, don't use a wildcard `*` with `git add`: '*' is interpreted by the shell.

The proper syntax is:

```
cd /app/gitfiles/ 
git add .
```

The '`.`' will add everything inside the current folder (which also includes the `.git` repository directory).

Comment: Though it's good advice, it's inaccurate. .git is not included when * gets _expanded_ by bash because it's a hidden directory.